# Code doesn't funtion right in PHP 7.3. Best way ti fix where it is backwards compatible with PHP 7.1 and 7.2, count() error

Tags: php, laravel

This is code within a laravel framework

```
 'mat_tactic_id' => count($request['red-mat_tactic_id']) > 0 ? implode(',',$request['red-mat_tactic_id']) : $request['red-mat_tactic_id'],
```

Here is the exception

> ErrorException (E_WARNING) count(): Parameter must be an array or an
>   object that implements Countable

I have tried is_Countable and that will fix but only in 7.3 it is not backwards compatible.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is even set and if it is an array like so:

```
isset($request['red-mat_tactic_id']) && is_array($request['red-mat_tactic_id'])
```

That means counting would work like this:

```
count((isset($request['red-mat_tactic_id']) && is_array($request['red-mat_tactic_id'])) ? $request['red-mat_tactic_id'] : [])
```

To have it better readable you would probably break that into two lines:

```
$isValueSet = $request['red-mat_tactic_id'] && is_array($request['red-mat_tactic_id'];
count(isValueSet ? $request['red-mat_tactic_id'] : [])
```

Depending on what exactly the content of the array index is, this could be simplified to:

```
count($request['red-mat_tactic_id'] ?? [])
```

Using the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/de/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).